# Enviar pedido automáticamente Magento

Tags: magento

Estou configurando o `Magento`, e os produtos são virtuais, são apostilas que são enviadas pro email.

Teria como, depois da pessoa finalizar a compra, ela receber a apostila no e-mail automaticamente, ou pelo menos o link de *download*?

Answer (score 0):

Basta criar um produto digital.

Se você estiver usando o retorno  automático de dados, assim que o pagamento for confirmado e o magento alterar o status, o cliente recebe o email com o link para download.